1980's ish movie, man kills wife and police send in substitute
A movie set in rural US. This is kind of the plot - the police chief in small town figures out a women has been murdered but husband tells him she is away. To catch him out they send in a "pretend" wife (who I think is chief's wife).
I thought that Fred Gwynne played a vicar in it but I can't find it in his list of movies.

A vicar? In the US?

@SystemDown - to someone from the UK, Vicar can be synonymous with priest / minister.

Your description reminds me vaguely of the 1986 movie Vanishing Act.

Based on the play "Trap for a Single Man" by Robert Thomas, this is the story of a newly married woman who disappears while on holiday. The wife returns but the husband denies it is his wife. The police inspector tries to discover what has happened.

And yes, Fred Gwynne is in it (as a priest).

Hardly vaguely - sounds like you're right on the money (added a bit to it).

Yes that is it..... And yes I meant Priest.
